# Getting children of an element in Puppeteer: element.children.length works but element.children returns undefined

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have this code snippet:

```js
    const historicalDataTable = await findElementByClass(
      "table",
      elementClass,
      page
    ); // This is a custom function I wrote. Works as expected.


    const tableBody = await historicalDataTable.$eval(
      "tbody",
      (el) => el.children.length
    );

    console.log(tableBody);
```

This works as expected and returns the correct amount of children. However when I do

```js
 const tableBody = await historicalDataTable.$eval(
      "tbody",
      (el) => el.children
    );
```

And remove the length, it returns undefined. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

`el.children` ([`Element#children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)) will yield an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is not serializable and can't be marshalled from the page's execution context into yours, so `evaluate` returns `undefined` instead.

Now, this isn't fully obvious when looking at the [`elementHandle.$eval` docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) as the only indication is that the return value is `<Promise<Serializable>>`, but it becomes clear from the [`executionContext.evaluate` docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-executioncontextevaluatepagefunction-args):

> - returns: <[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)<[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description)>> Promise which resolves to the return value of `pageFunction`
>
> [...]
>
> **If the function passed to the `executionContext.evaluate` returns a non-[Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) value, then `executionContext.evaluate` resolves to `undefined`.** DevTools Protocol also supports transferring some additional values that are not serializable by `JSON`: `-0`, `NaN`, `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, and bigint literals.

(Emphasis mine.)

`el.children.length` ([`HTMLCollection#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection/length)) on the other hand is a simple `number` which *is* serializable.

You have to do whatever you want to do with those elements inside of your `pageFunction` and return only some serializable value.

Alternatively, you could also use [`elementHandle.evaluateHandle`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-elementhandleevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) to return a [`JSHandle`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-class-jshandle) to the `HTMLCollection` and use that handle later in another call to an `evaluate`-type function. (Note that that would be the *only* thing you can do with it though. You couldn't access `.length` for example from your own execution context, only from another `pageFunction`<sup>1</sup>.)

---

<sub>**1:** This is not entirely true, since you could for example use [`jsHandle.getProperty`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-jshandlegetpropertypropertyname) to get another `JSHandle` for the `length`, followed by [`jsHandle.jsonValue`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-jshandlejsonvalue) to get the value as number - but both of these operations are asynchronous and probably it's a lot more efficient to write your code in such a way that you can handle all the necessary operations inside the page's execution context in the first place, without too many context switches.</sub>